# How to change DrawFocusRect pen width?

Tags: canvas, focus, c++builder, rect

I'm using C++ Builder and trying to use DrawFocusRect function:

```
DrawRect.left = X;
DrawRect.top = Y;
DrawRect.right = X;
DrawRect.bottom = Y;
Canvas->DrawFocusRect(DrawRect);
```

The problem is that this rectangle is barely visible. I tried this:

```
Canvas->Pen->Width = 2;
```

But no success. Is it possible to change the width of focus rectangle or is there some other approach I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method maps to the Windows API function [`DrawFocusRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162479.aspx). The documentation for which says:

> **Windows XP**: The focus rectangle can now be thicker than 1 pixel, so it is more visible for high-resolution, high-density displays and accessibility needs. This is handled by the `SPI_SETFOCUSBORDERWIDTH` and `SPI_SETFOCUSBORDERHEIGHT` in [`SystemParametersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947.aspx).

So you can indeed control the width. However, the modification you make applies to all programs on the current desktop. Which I am pretty sure is not what you desire. So my recommendation is that you do not use `DrawFocusRect` and instead draw this rectangle manually. It is very easy to do. It is just alternating black and white pixels and can be draw efficiently with `BitBlt`. And quite possibly other simpler ways.

Comment: When using a simple rectangle I have a problem deleting the rectangle before drawing a second one.. It looks messy.

Comment: Well, that's a somewhat different issue from that asked in the question. The usual reason for problems like that is that you are painting at the wrong time. Usually you paint in response to `WM_PAINT` (in VCL that translates to overridden `Paint` method or `OnPaint` event handlers). If you paint outside that time then you can encounter such issues.

Comment: I did it. In fact, it is quite simple - just changing pen color to white and redrawing the old rectangle (this will cause it to be like invisible) and then changing pen color to black before drawing a new rectangle. Thanks!